# Add menu items if page is custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to add menu items if page custom post type equal to 'contest'.

This code below only adds menu item if I am logged in. I do not know how to display if logged out. Or why it is not being displayed.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_menu_items', 10, 2);
function add_menu_items($items){
if ('contest' == get_post_type()){
        $items .= '<li><a href="#tire-promotion">Tire Promotion</a></li>';  
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: That code works for me logged in or out.  

Have you tested that code with a different post type, like a `page`? 

Otherwise, there might be some other code that is overriding your code.  You can try running your filter later by changing "10" to "99"

Comment: instead of using ```get_post_type()``` use ```is_page() or is_singular() or is_post_type_archive ()```  like these conditional template tags